# Add List to DF Column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I am trying to get the negative close price for buy signals as part of my code. Usually, when I add a column to a DF I do df["ColName"] = buyList and it works perfectly as I want and need. However, for some reason which hopefully you can help me with this code produces the following.

Instead of putting the individual value in the cell it's putting the whole list. But it's not doing this for the signal list [image: Cell as intended]
Can anyone shed some light on this for me? 
How do I turn my list buyList into a column in my df

[image: Cell not as intended]

```
signalList = []
buyList = []
sellList = []
for x,i in enumerate(df["Crossover"]):
    if i == True:
        if df['EMA ' + str(emaShort)].iloc[x] > df['EMA ' + str(emaLong)].iloc[x]:
            signal = "Buy"
            signalList.append(signal)
            buy = -df["Close"]
            buyList.append(buy)
            sell = 0
            sellList.append(sell)
        elif df['EMA ' + str(emaShort)].iloc[x] < df['EMA ' + str(emaLong)].iloc[x]:
            signal = "Sell"
            signalList.append(signal)
            buy = 0
            buyList.append(buy)
            sell = df["Close"]
            sellList.append(sell)
        elif df['EMA ' + str(emaShort)].iloc[x] == df['EMA ' + str(emaLong)].iloc[x]:
            print(df.iloc[x])
            print(x)
            print("******^^^^^^")
    elif i != True:
        signal = "None"
        signalList.append(signal)
        buy = 0
        buyList.append(buy)
        sell = 0
        sellList.append(sell)

df["Signal"] = signalList


df["Long Position"] = buyList
```

Comment: Hello, please simply your question to a more simple problem.

Comment: How do I turn my list buyList into a column in my df